# Crystal Cross Tab Report Group By Field

Tags: c#, winforms, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I need to create a mark ledger in crystal report. For that I have used cross tab reporting.

What I want is mark ledger of each class section should print in new page. Basically I will fetch all records (studentName,class, mark,subjectName,section ) from database and print each class student mark in a new page.

[image]

In image above there are two students in class 1st Section A similarly there are students in 1st class Section B, 2nd Class Section A and so on. I need to print student grouped by class and section and print on new page for new class and section student. How can I accomplish this on crystal report.

**I don't want to include more information than shown in table in crystal report.**

Comment: Group by class and student and then At group footer 1 go to section expert there check option `New Page After`

Comment: @Siva can you please explain in brief.

Comment: Are you aware of section expert in Crystal Reports? If yes the go to section expert and check whether you can find NewPageAfter option?

Comment: @Siva. Just started using Crystal Reports. Though I found the group by and new page after option you were stating about. Thank you.

Comment: ok so is your issue solved?

Comment: Yes I got output as I wanted.  Thank you